# Rails - Ransack doesn't query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have the folowing

Sale.rb

```
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :user

has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
has_many :products, through: :line_items
has_many :deposits

accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

sales_controller.rb

```
def index
  @q = Sale.ransack(params[:q])
  @sales = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

views/admin/sales/index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: admin_sales_path, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>

  <%= f.search_field :sku, placeholder: "SKU", class: "input perfil" %>
  <%= f.submit 'search', class: "btn btn-primary" %>  

<% end %>

<table class="table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th><%= sort_link @q, :sku, "SKU" %></th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @sales.each do |sale| %>

    ...
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally this is the log from the terminal:

```
Started GET "/admin/sales?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bsku%5D=sample&commit=search" for ::1 at 2016-11-24 00:29:33 -0600
Processing by Admin::SalesController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"sku"=>"sample"}, "commit"=>"search"}
Sale Load (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "sales".* FROM "sales"
Rendered admin/sales/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (7.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 361ms (Views: 346.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Everything seems to work fine, but nothing seems to be filtered.

As note I apply this same method for others models and they work fine.

Comment: <%= f.search_field :sku_eq, placeholder: "SKU", class: "input perfil" %>

Try it

Comment: wow I'm ashamed, super beginner error, you're right the problem is at the :sku_eq ("_eq" ending). Thanks.

Comment: adding it to solution please accpet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this

```
<%= f.search_field :sku_eq, placeholder: "SKU", class: "input perfil" %>
```

You have a little bit mistake

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple:
at views/admin/sales/index.html.erb

```
  ...
  <%= f.search_field :sku_eq, placeholder: "SKU", class: "input perfil" %>
  ...
```

I forgot to type the "_eq" ending at f.search_field :sku**_eq**

Comment: I think I just gave the answer below , it think its good to accept that as solution instead of adding duplicate one, Click on right tick